# Eigenvectors of Rotation+Scaling

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, rotations

I was thinking about $$A =\pmatrix{ \cos \theta & -\lambda \sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \lambda \cos \theta}$$ and its Eigenvectors and Eigenvalues.

Calculating with the characteristic polynomial gave me
$$x_{1,2}= \frac{1}{2}(\lambda \cos \theta + \cos \theta \pm \sqrt{(- \lambda \cos \theta - \cos \theta)^2-4\lambda}).$$

Which is fine, I think. However, I failed calculating the eigenvectors with $(A - \lambda I)v = 0$, and I assume there must be a better solution here.

For $\lambda=1$, we have to counterclockwise rotational $2\times 2$ matrix. And in general, $A$ can be considered as the composition of $\pmatrix{ \cos \theta & - \sin \theta \\ \sin \theta &  \cos \theta}$ and $\pmatrix{ 1 & 0 \\ 0 &  \lambda}$

The eigenvectors of these matrices are known. Does this tell me anything about the eigenvectors of A?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: There is a missing $4$ in your expression for the roots (the discriminant of $ax^2+bx+c$ is $b^2-\color{red}{4}ac$).

Comment: yes right. I did only post it wrong, on my calculations everything was correct. I edited it now. thanks.

Comment: Ok. Now, where did you fail to solve the $2\times2$ linear systems to find the eigenvectors? The answer to your last question is: no. In general, the eigenvalues and eigenvectors tell nothing about the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the product. Apart from the obvious: for instance, if $Bu=0$, then $u$ is an eigenvector of $AB$ for the eigenvalue $0$, since $ABu=0$.